# Dropdown Menu tabs not working on VS2010

Tags: html, css

I tried to create dropdown nav tabs for one of the maintabs on my homepage, I've used CSS to do it. It works fine on notepad, but not on visual studio master-page file. 
Can you please tell me where I got wrong?
The stylesheet and the code are below:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">

#navMenu
{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
} 

#navMenu ul {    
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
line-height:40px;    
}

#navMenu li 
{
margin: 0;
padding  :0; 
list-style:none; 
position: relative;
float: left;
background-color:gray;
color:#000; 
border-radius:5px;   
}

#navMenu ul li a 
{
text-align:center;
font-family:tahoma;
font-size:9.5pt;
text-decoration:none;
height:40px;
display:block;
color:#000;
border-right:white thin solid;    
}

#navMenu ul ul
{
position:absolute;
visibility:hidden;
top:40px;
}

#navmenu ul li:hover ul
{
visibility:visible;
}

#navMenu li:hover {
background-color:black;
color:#FFF;
}  

#navMenu ul li:hover ul li a:hover
{
background:black;
color:white; 
}  

#navMenu a:hover{
color:#FFF
}

</style>
</head>
<body onresize="window.location=window.location;" style="text-align:justify">
<form id="form1" runat="server">       
    <div> 
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
    <td colspan="5">
                        <div id="navMenu">
                        <ul> 
                        <li> 
                        <a href="~/" style="width:65px">Home</a>                    
                        </li>                            
                       <li>
                       <a href="~/" style="width:150px">tab1</a>                           
                       <ul >
                       <li><a href="~/" style="width:150px">subtab1</a>  </li>
                       <li><a href="~/" style="width:150px">subtab2</a>  </li>
                       <li><a href="~/" style="width:150px">subtab3</a>  </li>
                       <li><a href="~/" style="width:150px">subtab4</a>  </li>
                       </ul>
                       </li>
                       <li>                                                 
                       <a href="~/" style="width:125px">tab2</a>
                       </li>
                       <li>
                       <a href="~/" style="width:95px">tab3</a>
                       </li>
                       <li>
                       <a href="~/" style="width:65px">tab4</a>
                       </li>
                       <li>
                       <a href="~/" style="width:110px">tab5</a>
                       </li>
                       <li>
                        <a href="~/" style="width:165px">tab6</a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                       <a href="~/" style="width:200px">tab7</a>
                        </li>
                        </ul> 
                        </div>
        </td>
        </tr>

  </table>
  </div>
  </form>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: what do you mean with "it works fine on notepad"?

Comment: I mean as a html file on notepad it works fine on the browser.When I use the same code on an aspx file in VS and try to debug it the tabs appear, but not the dropdown.

Comment: have you got any other stylesheets included in your `.master` page?

Comment: I do but I am debugging this particular aspx file alone to check if the dropdown is working, and there are no links to the other style sheets from this aspx file. It still does not work.Do you think it has anything to do with the aspx.cs headers ? the following are the headers using System;
        using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

Comment: try to remove `runat="server"` from `head`

Comment: I had this '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">' on top of the page and once I removed this it works, Can someone please tell me exactly what in that is stopping the dropdown from working ? I cant have that removed as it supports other functionalities, But I need the dropdown to work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try with adding  tag as like below

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Comment: That's exactly what I have on my page and that's what is causing trouble. If I remove it the dropdown works fine.

Comment: DropDown tab is wokring in chrome,firefox,safari. But its not wokring in ie7-8 due to not support li:hover style.